# In a python logging is there a formatter to truncate the string?

Tags: python, logging, formatting, string-formatting, formatter

[Python logging](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#formatter-objects) formats strings with a syntax I don't see elsewhere in python, like

```
 'format': '%(name)s'
```

Is there any way to truncate an error message using the formatter, or do I need to override the LogRecord class for that?

This truncates parts of the message (though I can't find the documentation for this feature in the [normal places](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)):

```
 'format': '%(name).40s %(message).40s'
```

I'd rather truncate the entire formatted message, if possible (for an 80 column console, say).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is just the old style of string formatting.
I think you can just use a ".L", where L is the length to truncate the string to whatever length you like.  eg:

```
'format': '%(name).5s'
```

would truncate the length to 5 characters.

It's a little hard to find, but they actually do mention it in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

> The precision is a decimal number indicating how many digits should be displayed after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted with 'f' and 'F', or before and after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted with 'g' or 'G'. For non-number types the field indicates the maximum field size - in other words, how many characters will be used from the field content

Comment: yea I thought of that after writing the question and edited to include your suggestion above (which does work, for individual placeholders in the message).

Comment: So I guess my question doesn't really make sense. All you can pass to the formatter is an old-style string formatter. It doesn't make sense to ask about formatting the result of the formatting from within that formatter spec.

Comment: It looks likee you have a little more control in Python 3.2+, since you can  override LogRecord Creation: http://plumberjack.blogspot.ca/2010/12/getting-more-control-over-logrecord.html

Comment: There's no way to truncate from the left though is there?

Comment: @OrangeDog:  Interesting question, but I don't think so.

Comment: @Gerrat
If I'm not mistaken factories are interesting, but the `message` attribute  is only created at a later stage.
When the factory is called you have only the `msg` and the `args` attribute.